# Can we find an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $g′′(x)≠0$ for all $x∈(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:ℝ→ℝ$ be an entire function with infinitely many zeros.

My **question** is: Can we find an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $g′′(x)≠0$ for all $x∈(a,b)$? and $g′′$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and for any $y∈(a,b)$ a zero of $g′$ there are $x_1,x_2 ∈(a,b)$ so that

$$g(x_2)-g(x_1)=g′(y)(x_2-x_1)$$ with $g′(y)=0$. The motivation to this question can be found in: [A twice continuously differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777968/a-twice-continuously-differentiable-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes most definitely. I'm going to assume $g\neq 0$ since that immediately does not obey the condition on $g''$. The easy way to see this is that if no such interval existed, then since $g''$ is also entire, it would be the zero function (see the identity theorem from complex analysis). Thus $g(x) = ax+b$ but this only has finitely many zeroes and so we have a contradiction.

Comment: @ Cameron Williams: Is an explicite construction of $a$ and $b$ possible.

Comment: @DER Hmm. That would definitely have to be on a case-by-case basis, I think. I can't conceive of an easy way to extract the interval just from the function (or power series) itself that works in general.

Comment: @ Cameron Williams: Thank you very much.